# Ideas to complete a script to search in two files and extract a section of data

Tags: regex, perl

I have been doing a script that takes two files to extract a specific part of the data to make a new file.
If you want to see the complete file, here's a GitHub link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_to_extract_residues/tree/main)

File one (report file) is a type of file that reports me when a value is >=0.5 (column N°6 is the value that interests me).
This file is something like this (this is only a part):

```
AGY29650_2_NA   netOGlyc-4.0.0.13       CARBOHYD        2       2       0.0804934       .       .       
AGY29650_2_NA   netOGlyc-4.0.0.13       CARBOHYD        4       4       0.0925522       .       .       
AGY29650_2_NA   netOGlyc-4.0.0.13       CARBOHYD        13      13      0.0250116       .       .       
AGY29650_2_NA   netOGlyc-4.0.0.13       CARBOHYD        23      23      0.565981        .       .      
...
```

File two (fasta file) is a type of file used in bioinformatics, here is how looks it (this is only a part):

```
>AGY29650.2|NA spike protein
MTYSVFPLMCLLTFIGANAKIVTLPGNDA...EEYDLEPHKIHVH*
```

The purpose of my script is to take the column 1 and 4 when a value is >=0.5 in the column N°6, for example, the row N°4 is a #POSITIVE value, therefore the script takes the value in the column N°1 (AGY29650_2_NA, this is an ID) and the value in column N°4, 23 (position).
Then the script searches to match the ID (AGY29650_2_NA) in file two (fasta file) with the ID in this file AGY29650.2 and then looking for position 23 in the data, for example, the letter T in position 23:

```
MTYSVFPLMCLLTFIGANAKIV T LP
```

Then, the script print position 23 with 2 letters to the left and 2 letters to the right, the output:

```
IVTLP
```

The script is incomplete, however, here is the first problem that I couldn’t solve yet. The IDs between files have a few differences, for example:

```
AGY29650_2_NA (file one) and AGY29650.2 (file two)
```

To resolve this, a colleague recommends that I use regular expressions to select the ID in each file, for example:

```
s/^\s*([^_]+)_([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1.$2|$3/
```

My second problem is that I couldn't solve how to incorporate this regex into the script, I´m thinking in a foreach loop, maybe.
My third problem is a certificate if the script is really searching for the position (column N°4) and take the residues adjacent (two-letter to left and two to the right) for the final output.
Here is the incomplete script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;
​
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $in = $ARGV[1];
my %fastadata = ();
my @array_residues = (); 
my $seqio_obj = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $in,
                             -format => "fasta" );
while (my $seq_obj = $seqio_obj->next_seq ) {
  my $dd =  $seq_obj->id;
  my $ss =  $seq_obj->seq;
  ###my $ee =  $seq_obj->desc;
  $fastadata{$dd} = "$ss";
}
​
my $thres = 0.5; ### Selection of values in column N°5 with the following condition: >=0.5
​
# Open file
open (F, $file) or die; ### open the file or end the analyze
while(my $one = <F>) {### readline => F
    $one =~ s/\n//g;
    $one =~ s/\r//g;
    my @cols = split(/\s+/, $one); ### split columns
    next unless (scalar (@cols) == 7); ### the line must have 7 columns to add to the array
    my $val = $cols[5];
​
    if ($val >= 0.5) {
        my $position = $cols[3];
        my $id_list = $cols[0];
        if (exists($fastadata{$id_list})) {
            my $new_seq = $fastadata{$id_list};
            my $subresidues = substr($new_seq, $position -3, 6);

        } 
    }
}

close F;
​
```

I´m looking for help to incorporate the regex in the script and then to print the output that I´m looking for.

Any idea or comment is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested (since you did not post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but this should work:

```
    my $position = $cols[3];
    my $id_list = $cols[0];
    $id_list =~ s/^\s*([^_]+)_([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1.$2|$3/;   # Add this line
    if (exists($fastadata{$id_list})) {
```

This modifies the `$id_list` variable so that it should be compatible with your hash keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'if (!$#ARGV) { $h{$F[0]}=$F[3]; next }
            $F[0]=~s/^(\w+)_(\d+)_(\w+)/$1.$21|$3/;
            if ( $h{$F[0]} && $F[5] > 0.5 ) 
            { print substr $h{$F[0]}, $F[4]-3, 5 }' fasta.txt report.txt
```

`-a` splits fields of the record on whitespace and fills the special array `@F`: `$F[0]` is the 1st field, `$F[1]` is the 2nd field and so on.

If this is the 1st file, `fasta.txt`:  `if (!$#ARGV)`

Create the hash `%h` with the 1st field of `fasta.txt`, `AGY29650.2|NA`, as the key: `$h{$F[0]}`

Assign to it the 4th field of `fasta.txt`, `MTYSVFPLMCLLT...` as the value: `$h{$F[0]}=$F[3]`

*** Here ends the processing of `fasta.txt` and starts the processing of the next file, `report.txt` ***

Make the 1st field of `report.txt`, `AGY29650_2_NA`, look identically to that of the previous file, `AGY29650.2|NA`: `$F[0]=~s/^(\w+)_(\d+)_(\w+)/$1.$21|$3/`

If the 1st field of `report.txt`, `$F[0]`, exists as a key in `%h` and the 6th field of `report.txt` is more than 0.5: `if ( $h{$F[0]} && $F[5] > 0.5 )`

Take the substring `MTYSVFPLMCLLT...`:
`substr $h{$F[0]}` at the offset specified by the 5th field of `report.txt` minus 3: `$F[4]-3`, for 5 next characters and print them: `IVTLP`.